# Using RPostgreSQL to list the databases

Tags: r, postgresql, rpostgresql

I am looking for an R command to list the available databases in a PostgreSQL server. I am using RPostgreSQL package in R.

I know how to connect to the server but the only thing I need to know is how to list the names of available databases.

Answer (score 6):

Once you're connected to the server you can use this query:

```
dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE datistemplate = FALSE")
```

`con` is the name of your connection.